# Какую библиотеку выбрать для работы с Audio?

Tags: c#, аудио, библиотеки

Какую библиотеку выбрать для работы с Audio (WPF)?

**Обновление**

Планирую писать музыкальный плеер. Обязательная поддержка аудиостримов.

Comment: Ищите любую библиотеку под `.NET` с нужным функционалом. `WPF` тут совершенно ни при чем/

Comment: "Ищите любую библиотеку"
Да вот и ищу, собственно

Comment: Могу подсказать NAudio. Достаточно мощная и в открытом доступе.

Comment: nAudio слишком сложен для меня. Как проиграть mp3 файл, я понял, а как другие форматы - не понятно.

Comment: Также, как и mp3. В WPF: mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("file.avi");//или file.acc и т.д.